# How to calculate percentage of grand total using exclude?

Tags: tableau-api

I have sales data for each country which is split into different customer groups.

```
                     AT    CH     De    FL     Total

Customer Group A    100    72    488    16       676 
Customer Group B     53    62    280     3       398
Customer Group C     12     9    122     0       143

Total               165   143    890    19      1217
```

Now I would like to calculate the share of a particular customer group in a single country of the grand total of sales, e.g. for Customer Group B in DE I should get:

280/1217*100 = 23%

First I tried SUM([Sales]) / TOTAL(SUM([Sales])) to get percentage of sales in each country. Then I wanted to use customer group filter to see the share of a particular customer group. However, if I do this, the percentage is not correct, e.g. for Customer Group B in DE I get this:

280/398*100 = 70.3%

Using EXCLUDE would solve my problem... However, I am not really sure how to do this... I tried several options and none of these have worked...

{EXCLUDE [Customer Group]: SUM([Sales]) / TOTAL(SUM([Sales]))}

{EXCLUDE [Customer Group]: SUM([Sales])} / {EXCLUDE [Customer Group]: TOTAL(SUM([Sales]))}

Since I am new to tableau, I have no idea what the problem could be... Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude/Include LODs are calculated [only after the Dimension Filters](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.htm), so you need to use FIXED here. Also note that dimensions in filter shelf does not add to the [level of detail](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) even though it will affect the total.

you can use below calculation:

```
{FIXED [Customer Group],[Country]:SUM([Sales])}/{SUM([Sales])}
```

[image]